# How to create email server on my personal computer

Tags: email, personal-website, email-address

Suppose I own a domain name xyz.com and I want to create an email hello@xyz.com.
Ps. I am a newbie so this question may be lame. Correct me. Thank you

Comment: Sorry but the question is too board as you need a tutorial to follow and not answer. Most website hosting companies like GoDaddy, 1and1, 123Reg and so on, will be able to advise how they can provide those services too you.